# number of comparisons in simultaneous maximum and minimum element

Tags: algorithm, recursion

This is the question I'm trying to solve:

---

The following divide-and-conquer algorithm is proposed for finding the simultaneous maximum and minimum:

- If there is one item, it is the maximum and minimum
- if there are two items, then compare them and in one comparison you can find the maximum and minimum.
- Otherwise, split the input in two halves, divided as evenly as possibly (if N is odd, one of the two halves will have one more element than the other).
- Recursively find the maximum and minimum of each half, and then in two additional comparisons produce the maximum and minimum for the entire problem.

(b) Suppose N is of the form 3 + 2k. What is the exact number of comparisons used by this algorithm?

---

for this point (b), I tried to find a recurrence equation to solve but it didn't work.
I've tried

```
 T(n)= T(n/2+1) + T(n/2) + 3
```

where three is the minimum cost when I try 3 inputs.
any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recurrence equation should not have a term for the special case of n = 3. The algorithm gives you these facts:

- T(1) = 0
- T(2) = 1
- T(n) (n > 2) = T(floor(n/2)) + T(ceil(n/2)) + 2

That should be all you need to work out the answer.